# Western Digital not recognized by Windows after power Outage on windows

Tags: windows, macos, external-hard-drive

I have WD Essential Plus 1.5TB (formatted in NTFS). It was working fine under windows and mac mini. While it was connected to the mac mini, I had an power outage and now the HD is not being recognized under windows anymore.

Now on the mac mini the HD is fine and I can see my data. When I use ActiveBootDisk under windows, then I can see the data as well. I updated the drivers on windows machine and also updated the firmware on the HD, but its still not being recognized. Is there any way for me to fix the HD under windows without having to re-format it?

Answer (score 1):

From [My PC is not recognizing my WD Passport 120GB USB external drive](http://www.fixya.com/support/t852028-pc_not_recognizing_wd_passport_120gb_usb)

> Right click on "My Computer" and click
>   on "Manage" and then "Disk
>   Management",. you should see your WD
>   hard drive listed. then click on
>   "change driver letters and paths"  and
>   change it from the listed to another
>   drive.

If this doesn't work, you can also follow the instructions in this Microsoft Support article:
[A computer that is running Windows XP cannot detect a USB flash drive, an Apple iPod, or an external hard disk drive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925196/en-us)
but I suggest first creating a system restore point, so you ccould recover from any error resulting from the described registry manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you check it with Disk Utility on the Mac Mini does it report any problems?

(I had a similar problem but between a Mac Pro and Mac Mini - power cut while attached to the Mini and no longer show up on the Pro.  Ran Disk Utility and it reported a problem, although it couldn't fix it itself, I had to use DiskWarrior)

Comment: I will check with disk-utility. Did DiskWarrior fix your hd without having it to re-format?

Answer (score 0):

Western Digital supplies tools to check the drive and report issues. DataLifeguard (WINDLG) is downloadable at westerndigital.com  May give you a clue what happened.  There are tests in WINDLG that are non-destructive to the data.